# How much does each test case consume in QTest for C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt, qttest

Is there a simply way to knowing how much time consume each test case in QT Test Framework for C++?

It will be incredible helpful to getting some metrics.

Comment: It depends on your computer, the complexity of the unit test, your compiler and the compiler settings you used for the unit tests, what other programs are running at the same time, etc., etc...  The best (and most useful) thing to do, is just keep a record of how long each test takes and always do it on the same machine - then monitor the time changes as you make code changes.

Comment: @cbamber85 I think this is exactly what I wants to do.

Comment: @leemes Ah, I thought he was asking us how long _will_ they take...

Comment: @cbamber85 great information. I'll definitely put on practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom Timer class which starts a usually monotonic elapsed timer on creation and prints the elapsed time on deletion (see [`QElapsedTimer::elapsed()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qelapsedtimer.html#elapsed)):

**timer.h:**

```
#include <QElapsedTimer>
class Timer {
public:
    Timer() {
        timer.start();
    }
    ~Timer() {
        qint64 ms = timer.elapsed();
        qDebug("Time needed: %s ms%s", ms,
               timer.isMontonic() ? "" : " (WARNING: non-monotonic)");
    }
private:
    QElapsedTimer timer;
}
```

The benefit of using `QElapsedTimer` over `QTime` is that Qt will try to use the best available monotonic timer on each platform. `QTime` is not guaranteed to be montonic: it will decrease when time synchronization daemon/service adjusts the clock, etc.

Now insert the line `Timer t;` at the beginning of each test case you want to measure the time of; no more code. This simply creates a `Timer` object, which starts the internal timer, and deletes the object when it gets out of scope (which is at the end of the method) and thus prints the elapsed time:

**Your test case (.cpp):**

```
#include "timer.h"
...
void TestClass::myTestCase1()
{
    Timer t; //the only line needed to add to your test case

    ... //the code for test case
}
void TestClass::myTestCase2()
{
    Timer t; //the only line needed to add to your test case

    ... //the code for test case
}
...
```

Comment: @SantiagoAgüero Glad I could help. Note that Kuba Ober improved my answer. You should check out the edited version and use QElapsedTimer rather than QTime. (Thanks Kuba Ober for your edit!)

Answer (score 1):

`time_t t = time(0);` will define a time variable in milliseconds since the epoch, and set it to the current moment.  Fire one of these off before testing, one after testing, and compare the two to get how long the test took.  As cbamber85 noted, it varies based on a number of things, so if you want your metrics to mean anything, you need to keep your platform stable (and even then they'll only be significant as a relative thing) but it's at least somethign you can work with.

Comment: alternatively you could use `QTime t = QTime::currentTime()` which has a nice `toString` method. (use `toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz")` to include milliseconds)

Comment: QTime is less likely to be monotonically increasing than QElapsedTimer, the latter is better for this job and was specifically designed for such elapsed timing.